# Speeding up OpenNLP's POSTagging when using it for several texts

Tags: java, performance, serialization, nlp, opennlp

I'm currently working on a keyphrase extraction tool, which should provide tag suggestions for texts or documents on a website. As I am following the method proposed in this paper: [A New Approach to Keyphrase Extraction Using Neural Networks](http://www.ijcsi.org/papers/7-2-3-16-25.pdf) I am using the OpenNLP toolkit's POSTagger for the first step, i.e. candidate selection.

In general the keyphrase extraction works pretty well. My problem is that I have to perform this expensive loading of the models from their corresponding files every time I want to use the POSTagger:

```
posTagger = new POSTaggerME(new POSModel(new FileInputStream(new File(modelDir + "/en-pos-maxent.bin"))));
tokenizer = new TokenizerME(new TokenizerModel(new FileInputStream(new File(modelDir + "/en-token.bin"))));
// ...
String[] tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text);
String[] tags = posTagger.tag(tokens);
```

This is due to the fact that this code is not on the scope of the webserver itself but inside a "handler" with a lifecycle including only handling one specific request. My question is: **How can I achieve loading the files only once?** (I don't want to spend 10 seconds on waiting for the models to load and using it just for 200ms afterwards.)

My first idea was to serialize the **POSTaggerME** (**TokenizerME** resp.) and deserialize it every time I need it using Java's built-in mechanism. Unfortunately this doesn't work – it raises an exception. (I do serialize the classifier from the WEKA-toolkit which classifies my candidates at the end in order to not having to build (or train) the classifier every time. Therefore I thougth this may be applicable to the POSTaggeME as well. Unfortunately this is not the case.)

In the case of the Tokenizer I could refer to a simple **WhitespaceTokenizer** which is an inferior solution but not that bad at all:

```
tokenizer = WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE;
```

But I don't see this option for a reliable POSTagger.

Comment: When you say you tried to serialise the object, do you mean serialise it to disk? There doesn't seem to me to be any reason to think that would be any quicker than loading the model again (from disk). I think the answer to this lies in keeping the model in memory but I don't know enough about the environment you are deploying in.

Comment: Yes I meant to serialise it to disk. My motivation was that I thought this would be similar to serialising the WEKA classifier. But I realized now that it isn't: in the case of the classifier the actual memory size used is fairly small (whereas the process of creating it is time-consuming) – in the case of a POSTagger one cannot reduce the size of the model. So maybe I could make use of a Singleton to load everything into memory only once. But in this case I may encounter problems if many handlers try to get access to it simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, the approach in dmcer's answer is probably what you want. I don't think you need to worry about synchronisation, though, as the models will only ever be read from, not written to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your tokenization/POS-tagging pipeline in a **[singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)**.

If the underlying OpenNLP code isn't thread safe, put the calls in synchronization blocks, e.g.:

```
// the singletons tokenization/POS-tagging pipeline 
String[] tokens;
synchronized(tokenizer) { 
   tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text);
}
String[] tags;
synchronized(posTagger) { 
   tags = posTagger.tag(tokens);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll use this code. Furthermore I will research if I can use an n-gram extraction approach for selecting candidates as it is done e.g. by Maui Indexer (http://code.google.com/p/maui-indexer/). This should be more economical regarding memory used.